# Remove all Deleted items including reminders

Tags: vba, outlook

I have many alerts and recently discovered that when they are deleted, they only fo to deleted items and cause issues so I am trying to remove the alerts with a macro.

```
Public Sub ClearDeleted()
    Dim olNS As NameSpace
    Dim deletedFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olNS = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set deletedFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
    
    myCount = deletedFolder.Items.Count
    For ii = 1 To myCount Step 1
        Debug.Print ii & " " & deltedFolder.Items(ii)
    Next ii
End Sub
```

I am not deleting here but printing the subject name and it works for regular emails, but if it gets to a reminder it fails with Object doesn't support this property or method.

I found that if I focus on only appointments and add.

```
Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
'In the loop:
Set objAppointment = deletedFolder.Items.Item(ii)
Debug.Print ii & " " & objAppointment.Subject
```

This works for the alerts only, but fails with Type Mismatch when it gets to a regular email.

How can I have one macro work for both emails and alerts? Thank you.

Comment: `Debug.Print ii & " " & deltedFolder.Items(ii)` typo

Comment: Go backwards  - `For ii = 1 To myCount to 1 Step -1` because you're deleting items as you loop.  And check the item type before trying to do anything with it: `If TypeOf deletedFolder.Items(ii) Is AppointmentItem Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
```

use

```
Dim objAppointment As Object
```

and check that the `Class` property identifies it as appointment `26 (OlObjectClass.olAppointment)`:

```
if objAppointment.Class = 26 Then
  ...
```

You also need to loop backwards, otherwise you will be decreasing the collection count while looping:

```vb
dim Items As Object
dim Items as Items
set Items = deletedFolder.Items
myCount = Items.Count
For ii = myCount to 1 Step -1
  set Item = Items(ii)
  if Item.Class = 26 Then
    Item.Delete
  End If
next ii
```

Comment: Thank you, That works perfectly. `dim Item As Object` is all that was needed to work as both appointments and emails have the `.Delete` method. Very happy to know appointments are Class 26 and emails are Class 53.